# Drupal Rules - Condition "Civicrm Contact has email" appears to not be working

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity, drupal-rules

*The desired outcome was to create a drupal user record if and only if an email exists on the contact  - when a membership was created/updated.*

To do this I wanted to add the condition "CiviCRM Contact has Email".

Testing this on multiple sites I've come to the conclusion that it doesn't appear to be working as advertised - it's not returning true when the associated contact has an email.

I've tested using these two stripped down rules - (It's not working on civicrm contact is updated either) - pasted below.

The only think I can think off that could be causing this is that the data selector is not correct? I tested this by outputting this using the debug action but perhaps it needs an ID not a "contact" or vice versa? I can't see any errors in the drupal log that would indicate this though. The rule is returning successfully - it's not generating any warnings.

Membership update

```
{ "rules_test_2" : {
    "LABEL" : "Test 2",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "civicrm", "rules", "devel" ],
    "ON" : { "civicrm_membership_edit" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "civicrm_entity_contact_hasemail" : {
          "contact" : [ "civicrm-membership:contact-id-contact" ],
          "location" : "0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Has email" } },
      { "devel_debug" : { "value" : [ "civicrm-membership:contact-id-contact" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Contact update

```
{ "rules_test" : {
    "LABEL" : "Test",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "civicrm", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "civicrm_contact_edit" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "civicrm_entity_contact_hasemail" : { "contact" : [ "civicrm-contact" ], "location" : "0" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Has emali" } } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/blob/7.x-2.x/civicrm_entity.module#L3237

remove the ampersand from the $contact parameter

```
function civicrm_entity_contact_has_location_element_email($contact, $location_type_id) {
```

This is a bug, can you make an issue in the CiviCRM Entity project issue queue? I need to trace back how this code got that way, and see if there's any other reasons why it is as it is now before I put it into the release

But I can't think of any reason why it should